# How to select another item from web store using this xpath for Selenium test?

Tags: python, xpath, selenium-webdriver

```
http://store.nike.com/us/en_us/pw/mens-jackets-vests/7puZobr?ipp=106

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@id='exp-gridwall-wrapper']/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/p").click()
```

With the current xpath, my selenium script is selecting an item in the store that is out of stock.  What I want to do is change the xpath to select the next item in the store, or another item.  I figure I could just change the last div[2] to div[3], but that does not select anything.

How do I select another item in the store (link provided above), using the currently provided xpath?  Is there a more "efficient" xpath I can use?

Answer (score 0):

All the product name `p` tags have the class `product-display-name`. Therefore you can simply select on p elements that contain that class:

```
//p[contains(@class, 'product-display-name')]
```

To get the nth element you can use the following xpath:

```
(//p[contains(@class, 'product-display-name')])[n]
```

The `[]` operator has higher precedence than the `//` abbreviation, therefore you need to use the brackets `()`